# NPC movement in the array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array

I am doing a an array game, below is my Board class, which paints the array and spawns 5 hunters at 11,11, my 'route1' method should be the one to move hunters around whenever the player moves, however my hunter.x and hunter.y stay 11 after each re-paint, how do I fix this?

```
  public class Board { 

    public String emptyfield = "-";
    public  String [][]a2 = new String[12][12];
 public Hunter hunters[] = new Hunter[5];

public void paint(){

    int numHunters =5 ;
    for (int i =0; i < numHunters; i ++){
        hunters[i] = new Hunter(11,11,"H");
    }
Player player = new Player();
        for (int r = 0 ; r < a2.length; r++){
            for (int c= 0; c <a2[r].length; c++){
                a2 [r][c] = emptyfield;
                a2[Player.x][Player.y] = Player.name;
                for (int i = 0; i < numHunters; i++){
                     Hunter h = hunters[i];
                     a2[h.x][h.y]=h.name;

                }
                System.out.print(" "+a2[r][c]);
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("     Strength:  "+Player.hp);System.out.println("      Score  "+Player.score);

    }

public void route1(){
    Board board = new Board();
    Hunter Hunter = new Hunter(11,11,"H");
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random number = new Random(2);
    int random = number.nextInt(2);
     if(random ==1)
        Hunter.x = Hunter.x -1;
    else
       Hunter.y = Hunter.y -1;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I read this correctly, you are recreating all your hunters at position 11,11 each time you call paint.

```
public void paint(){

    int numHunters =5 ;
    for (int i =0; i < numHunters; i ++)
    {
        hunters[i] = new Hunter(11,11,"H");
    }
```

This code is replacing your array of hunters each time paint is called, erasing any changes made later on in code.  You need to move (new Hunter(11,11,"H") to somewhere that is only called once.